# Proper Way to Programatically Send Mail Using Google Apps

Tags: email, gmail, google-apps

I have a domain which uses Google Apps for Business to handle email. I already have it mostly set up--MX records point to the correct location and my domain is verified.

I'm now writing a python app (with Django) that will need to serve mail from my domain. What's the correct way to do this with Google? Should I create a Google Apps "user" for the organization as a whole, and then [authenticate via SMTP](https://developers.google.com/gmail/oauth_overview) as that user and send mail from there?

The [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/?hl=en) says that it

> is the best choice for authorized access to a user's Gmail data.

and that

> Automated or programmatic message sending

is a typical use case. However, I'm not trying to access *a user's* data or send mail on behalf of a user, but on behalf of my domain. What's the correct way to proceed?

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use SMTP or the Gmail API based on your description. In both cases, you'll need some sort of service account to send mail from. With SMTP, as you mentioned, you'll be authorizing via the instructions you linked.

If you choose to use the Gmail API route, you'll be authorizing the API usage with the account. The Gmail API has many other use cases (e.g. to access user's data) but you're only using it to send emails on behalf of a service account you control.